# The viewcontrollers are not loading when I try to cache a users data and keep the user logged in with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm coding an iOS app and trying to keep a user logged in with Parse so they don't have to type in their login information every time they open the app. I used Parse's formatting, and even tried different variations of code using examples I found in some of the app tutorials Parse has made. Regardless, I can't get the viewcontrollers to load properly when trying these methods. Each time I either get a black screen, or a black screen with a white navigation bar on top. I feel like it's a simple fix, but I can't find my mistake. Some help would be appreciated, thanks! My most recent code is below:

// If we have a cached user, we'll get it back here

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

if (currentUser) 
{
    // Skip straight to the main view.
    HomePageViewController *homePageViewController = [[HomePageViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = homePageViewController;
}

else
{
    // Go to the welcome screen and have them log in or create an account.
    WelcomeViewController *welcomeViewController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = welcomeViewController;
}

[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

Comment: Are you generating all of the content for your view programatically or are you using nibs or storyboard?

Comment: I'm using a storyboard. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a storyboard you need to instantiate your view controllers from the storyboard, otherwise you will end up with an empty view (as you are getting).

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

if (!currentUser) 
{
    // Go to the welcome screen and have them log in or create an account.
    self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"welcomePage"];
}
```

You need to change "welcomePage" to the identifier for these scenes in your storyboard.

Comment: It's getting there, but now I get a blank white screen instead of a black one, haha. I named my identifiers to the ones you suggested. I suspect there might have been a problem with storyBoard name, as my "Main storyboard file base name" is just "Main". I changed to storyboardWithName:@"Main" and there are no compile or run errors, but still a blank white screen when the view loads. Any thoughts? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Have you successfully tested your storyboard to ensure that the view loads properly without your code - ie. just specifying one of the scenes as the initial scene in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, the storyboard works perfect when I remove or comment out the code. I can successfully sign up, send data to parse, and log in using the saved data. When I try to keep the user logged in however, all I get is a blank screen.

Comment: I realised that if you make your home the standard initial scene, then you only need to handle the not-logged-in case and I have updated my question.  I also created a quick sample app and the code worked correctly to select the appropriate view controller. I assume that the code you have shown is in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! I felt like I was running my head into a wall for hours yesterday trying to get it to work, haha. You saved me another day of headache. Much appreciated